# Sketch the heart and indicate its orientation with arrows $ r = 1 - \cos(\theta)$. Find the area enclosed by the heart

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

Hi all I am trying to figure out how to sketch the heart. Here is what I have tried so far:
$$r = 1 - \cos(\theta) \\
r(r = 1 - \cos(\theta)) \\
r^2 = r - r\cos(\theta) \\
$$
Use the fact that
$$r =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \text{ and } x=r\cos(\theta) \text{ to rewrite the equation as , } \\
x^2 + y^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + x \\
x^2 - 2x + y^2 - y = 0 \\
\text{Completing the square gives } \\ 
(x-1)^2 + (y-\frac{1}{2})^2 = -\frac{5}{4}\\
\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-\frac{1}{2})^2 } = \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}  \\
(x-1) + (y-\frac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \\
(y-\frac{1}{2}) = -(x-1) + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} \\
y = -(x-1) + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}} + \frac{1}{2} \\
y = -x + \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}
$$From here we can get a table of values and sketch the function. For the area the formula is
$$\frac{1}{2} \int f(\theta)^2 \,d\theta$$
So should it be
$$\frac{1}{2} \int y = -x + \frac{\sqrt{5} + 3}{2}$$

Comment: The conversion has at least one error; notice your final result $y$ is the equation for a line, not a cardioid! Nonetheless, it's more convenient to work directly with the polar equation, unless the problem specifically requires you to do otherwise.

Comment: $\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)^2 + \left(y-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 }$ is not at all the same as $\left( x-\dfrac 1 2 \right) + \left( y - \dfrac 1 2 \right)$. If you could do something like that, then $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$ would be the same as $3+4$, but $\sqrt{3^2+4^2} =5$ whereas $3+4=7$. $\qquad$

Comment: Your last statement also has an error, since you have forgotten the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily draw the shape by substituting convenient values for $\theta$. To find the area, use the formula $\displaystyle A=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^{b}r(\theta)^2d\theta$. The integration proceeds as follows:

$$2\cdot \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi}(1-\cos \theta)^2d\theta$$

$$ \int_0^{\pi}(1-2\cos \theta+\cos^2\theta )d\theta$$

$$ \int_0^{\pi}1-2\cos \theta+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2 x )d\theta$$

$$ \int_0^{\pi}\frac{3}{2}-2\cos \theta+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2 x )d\theta$$

$$ (\frac{3}{2}\theta-2\sin \theta+\frac{1}{4}\sin 2 x) \Bigg|_0^{\pi}$$

$$\frac{3}{2}\pi-0+0-(0-0+0)=\frac{3}{2}\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Drawing the figure is the hard part by far. For example, Matlab doesn't have a method for directly adding arrows to a curve like this. What I tried was to draw a little right-pointing arrowhead with its tip at $(0,0)$ and some reasonable size. Then at a selection of points along the path, I rotated that arrow counterclockwise by $\text{atan2}\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta},\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)$ and then added $(x(\theta),y(\theta))$ to its coordinates. Here is my Matlab code:

```
% cardioid.m

% Plot main curve
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,500);
r = 1-cos(theta);
x = r.*cos(theta);
y = r.*sin(theta);
plot(x,y,'b-');
hold on;
% Plot arrows
asize = 0.07;
axy = [-1 0 -1;
    -1 0 1]*asize/sqrt(2);
% We want fewer points
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,10);
% Avoid the cusp
theta = theta(2:end-1);
r = 1-cos(theta);
x = r.*cos(theta);
y = r.*sin(theta);
% Orientations needed
drdtheta = sin(theta);
phi = atan2(sin(theta).*drdtheta+r.*cos(theta), ...
    cos(theta).*drdtheta-r.*sin(theta));
for k = 1:length(theta),
    R = [cos(phi(k)) -sin(phi(k));
        sin(phi(k)) cos(phi(k))];
    xy = R*axy;
    plot(xy(1,:)+x(k), xy(2,:)+y(k),'b-');
end
% Titles and labels
axis equal;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
title('Cardioid with Direction');
hold off;
```

And here is the figure it drew:
[image: Figure 1]

Having drawn the cardioid, finding its area is anticlimactic:
$$A=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1-\cos\theta}r\,dr\,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac12\left(1-2\cos\theta+\cos^2\theta\right)d\theta=\frac12(2\pi)\left(1-0+\frac12\right)=\frac{3\pi}2$$
Where we have used the average values for $1$ of $1$, for $\cos\theta$ of $0$ and for $\cos^2\theta$ of $\frac12$ over the interval of length $2\pi$ to zip through the azimuthal integral.

Comment: I disagree that drawing the cardioid is the harder part. Substituting $0, \pi/2, \pi, 3\pi/2$, and $2\pi$ yield enough information for at least a rough sketch.

Comment: Even values such as $\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$ aren't that bad, as long as one knows that $1/\sqrt{2}<1$.

Comment: But you can't post a drawing like that! Posting to this forum requires rendering the cardioid along with the arrows in some sort of software. Compare the $36$ lines of Matlab to draw vs. $1$ line of MathJax to integrate. I wanted to show how to draw the direction arrows on the figure in Matlab; there was no point in posting otherwise.

Comment: I've seen people post handwritten drawings. Of course they look less professional, but if the OP just needs a sketch, then evaluating $1-\cos \theta$ is surely easier than taking an iterated integral.

Comment: I dunno about that. I got the job done in $1$ line, and I didn't have a typo in my original formula for the area like some people I might mention, either.

Comment: Thank you for the (rather passive) correction! Fixed! Anyway, all I'm saying is that if the OP just needs a sketch, evaluating $1-\cos \theta$ is simpler than taking an integral.  If the author needs to publish this drawing, then by all means, use software. But using software to draw a crude heart seems like overkill to me if you only need a sketch.

Comment: We will just have to agree to disagree. Trying to carry 'garbage' formulas like $$A=\int_{\theta_{\min}}^{\theta_{\max}}\frac12(r(\theta))^2d\theta$$ around in your head when it's really no extra effort to use the more general and fundamental formula I used is counterproductive in my view since it's easy to forget about things like sign conventions and factors of $2$ and the like in the face of all the other stuff you needed your long-term memory for in the years since graduation. I further claim my point about the drawing: it delayed my post, and yours still hasn't been posted yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40038/discussion-between-zz20s-and-user5713492).